# Is there a way of validating a powershell script?

Tags: c#, powershell

My app allows users to enter powershell scripts that it will run for you later. Is there a straightforward way to be able to validate the powershell script without running it, so that when the user enters it the program could report syntax errors?

Thanks.

Comment: read here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2009/09/07/parsing-powershell-scripts.aspx

Comment: Thanks... that comment led me to this which looks like it's just what I need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182539(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PowerShell v2 you have tokenizer that can process script without running it. Look at class System.Management.Automation.PSParser and it's static method Tokenize:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psparser(v=vs.85).aspx

In v3 it's gets even better, there is whole language namespace/ AST support:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language(v=vs.85).aspx

HTH
Bartek

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a function to automate the process: Test-PSScript, you can find it [on my blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2009/09/07/parsing-powershell-scripts.aspx)

```
#Requires -Version 2

function Test-PSScript
{

   param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
      [Alias('PSPath','FullName')] 
      [System.String[]] $FilePath,

      [Switch]$IncludeSummaryReport
   )

   begin
   {
      $total=$fails=0
   }

   process
   {
       $FilePath | Foreach-Object {

         if(Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf)
         {
            $Path = Convert-Path –Path $_ 

            $Errors = $null
            $Content = Get-Content -Path $path 
            $Tokens = [System.Management.Automation.PsParser]::Tokenize($Content,[ref]$Errors)

            if($Errors)
            {
               $fails+=1
               $Errors | Foreach-Object { 
                  $_.Token | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $Path -PassThru | `
                  Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty -Name ErrorMessage -Value $_.Message -PassThru
               }
            }

           $total+=1 
         }  
      }
   } 

   end 
   {
      if($IncludeSummaryReport) 
      {
         Write-Host "`n$total script(s) processed, $fails script(s) contain syntax errors."
      }
   }
}
```